# Quickest and/or most scenic route to Show Low, Arizona from Phoenix by car?

Tags: road-trips, routes, scenic-routes, arizona, phoenix

What's the best route to get to Show Low, Arizona from Phoenix.  I can either go through Payson or Globe.

By "best" I mean which route is faster or more scenic?

Comment: Given that the route is 3 hours and there is not much in the way of anything on either route it makes no difference.  If you want to do sightseeing I'd pick a landmark and then pick a route.

Comment: If you detail what you may want to see we can provide example of routes that include what you want but, as it stands, this question is "primarily opinion-based".

Comment: **Yes.** It is very unlikely that both routes are equally fast *and* equally scenic.

Answer (score 5):

Google Maps shows your two proposed routes as having a less than 5 mile and less than 10 minute difference. Which one is "faster" becomes almost entirely irrelevant at that point.

So we're left with "more scenic." Of the two routes, one (via Payson) runs almost entirely through [Tonto National Forest](http://www.fs.usda.gov/tonto/) and [Sitgreaves National Forest](http://www.fs.usda.gov/asnf), while the other (via Globe) is almost entirely outside the national forest boundaries.

Routes passing through national forests are highly likely to be scenic, or have easy access to scenic overlooks, points of interest, etc. The other route which skirts the national forests didn't look all that scenic from a couple of quick peeks at random points on Google Maps.

Though, if you're stopping a lot to take in the scenery, then that will certainly slow down your trip!

So I would say, if you want a fast, scenic drive, go via the Payson route, and if you want a fast, boring drive, go via the Globe route.

Answer (score 1):

Going thru Globe is not boring. You will pass thru the Salt River Canyon, quite beautiful area.
But remember there is construction going on 6pm-6am Monday through Thursday. Happy travels.